# Need a little help reading aid items

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Most of the aid items I've used in Fallout 3 and New Vegas were fairly self-explanatory; however this is because as a matter of course (particularly in NV where RadAway is more scarce) I tended to avoid irradiated aid items.

I'm currently playing as a melee/unarmed/survivalist -- and will need to eat to replenish HP (in order to get the Desert Survivalist achievement). In doing so, I will need to consume irradiated food on occasion.

So when I see an entry such as RadRoach Meat (`Rads +9, HP +1(5s)`), I wonder:

Is it that it immediately adds 9 to my radiation, and gives me 1 hit point per second, or does it add 9 to my radiation every second while simultaneously adding 1 to my hit points per second?

Comment: You can go to any doctor and get your rads removed for 100 caps. Unless you're trying to avoid that :).

Comment: @Viper: I know, but I'm cheap. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only adds +9 radiation immediately when you eat it, then it gives you 5 HPs over 5 secods, 1HP every second.

You have to note that the (5s) description is only part of the HP +1 effect, not the Rad effect.

Comment: There are a few things that will add radiation over time but they are few and far between.  The entry will read "rads 3(5s), hp".